# After passing a reference to an method, any mods using that reference are not visible outside the method - Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reference, object

I am passing the reference of *name* to *mod_name*, I modify the referenced object from within the method but the change is not visible outside of the method, if I am referring to the same object from all locations how come the value is different depending on where I reference it?

```
name = "Jason"

puts name.object_id      #19827274

def mod_name(name)
  puts name.object_id    #19827274
  name = "JasonB"
end

puts name.object_id      #19827274

puts name                #Jason
```

String might be a bad example, but I get the same result even if I use a Fixnum.

Comment: Good point Jimmy - did not see that option :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Greg mentions, in your example you're creating a new local variable called `name` that is shadowing your parameter. This is due to behavior called *copy-on-write*. If you wanted the function to affect the object the parameter references, you could use `replace` instead of doing an assignment, like this:

```
def mod_name(name)
  name.replace('JasonB')
end
```

Comment: I thought I was passing a reference to an object as the argument & not the actual object itself, that both *name|* variables would be references pointing to the same underlying object.

Comment: I'm not sure that "copy-on-write" has anything to do with this. @Jimmy, could you post some prooflinks?

Comment: I'm not sure why I called this copy on write. (It's been a few years since I wrote this.) In any case, I was certainly not referring to behavior of memory when forking a process.

Answer (score 1):

mutating the content of a string :

```
def mod_name(name)
  print "%i %s\n" % [name.object_id, name]
  name[0..-1] = "what"
  print "%i %s\n" % [name.object_id, name]
  name << "ever"
  print "%i %s\n" % [name.object_id, name]
end
```

Also :

- in your sample code you never call the mod_name function.
- You seemed to believe that writing 'var = x' would change var's content. It can't. It can only change what object gets pointed to by var. Asking for its object_id before and after affectation would have showed that it was indeed another string.
- There's no way to make this function work with Fixnums because Fixnums are immutable in ruby. You can't make any modification to a Fixnum. Worse, they're not even passed by reference and in some corner cases won't behave like proper objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have gotten answers to the question you asked.  Maybe you need an answer to what would have caused you to ask this question.

```
name = "jason"

def mod_name(name)
  local_name = "jasonb"
end

puts name = mod_name(name)
puts name
```

Depending upon where this method lives (if it were in a class for example) maybe you would utilize an instance variable `@name` and depending upon the scope wouldn't have to be passed.

```
@name = "jason"

def mod_name()
  @name = "jasonb"
end

puts @name
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `name = "JasonB"` line is creating a new local variable named `name` and assigning "JasonB" to it, rather than modifying the string which was passed in.

Comment: So is there anyway, using the reference passed to modify the original name object from within the mod_name method?

Comment: @Jason: No. Ruby is pass-by-value. Always. You *can* obviously modify the object the reference points to (unless it is frozen or an immediate value), but you can not modify the reference.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Ruby is not pass-by-value. it is allways "pass-by-reference".

Comment: @Pedro: Ruby does always pass parameters by value, as Jörg said.  If it passed them by reference, then @Jason's code would have worked, since it would have had a reference to `name`.  However, all values in Ruby are references.  Consequently, Ruby is effectively a pass-references-by-value language, which makes it seem like it is passing things by reference in many (most?) cases.  Apparently (according to Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy), Ruby tends to call itself pass-by-reference, but this is directly at odds with the normal definition of the term (also at Wiki).

Comment: @absz - that was where I was getting confused, thought that I was passing a reference to the object and not the passing underlying object itself so that the name variables within and outside the method  where both pointing to the same object / modifying the same object.